# Cargar una base exceptuando un elemento dinamicamente

Tags: php

quisiera saber como podría cargar un listado de una base exceptuando un elemento por su id.
Envío el id de un elemento con un botón mediante método Get a otra página donde hago la carga de dicho elemento.
Lo que busco hacer es, que en otra sección de esa misma página pueda cargar el listado completo al que pertenece ese elemento pero quisiera excluir  el elemento que recibo mediante get.

Lo que intento lograr es el resultado que muestran otras webs que he visto en el que muestran algo asi como: "también te podría interesar..."  ojala se entienda.

http://unidadesdentales.pe/venta.php?de=lamparas_led_fotocurado&&clav=lampara-led-de-fotocurado-woodpeckerled-g#lamparaledfotocurado

Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podría recuperar todos los datos del listado de la base de datos y mostrarlos con un bucle, en ese bucle añades un `if` para que el elemento con el id que haya recibido por GET no se muestre (en php creo que es `continue`) de manera que el bucle siga sin mostrar el elemento.

Sería algo así:

```
$elemento = $_GET['valor']
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {    
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($fila["imgen"] == $elemento) {
          continue;
        }
        mostrar_elemento();
    }
}
```

Comment: hola que tal, disculpa mi falta de experiencia pero estuve intentando implementar lo que me indicas, pero no me sale, yo normalmente uso un  bucle while como el que puedes ver a continucion, aunque quiero implementarlo bien, no me es posible obtener el resultado                   :<?php
     $peticion="SELECT nombre FROM lista";
     $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$peticion);
     while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
       if($fila == $elemento) {
        continue; 
      }
      echo $fila["nmbre_prducto"]."<br>"; 
     }
   ?>

Comment: En la parte de `$fila["nombre_producto"]` está mal, ya que el valor que introduzcas de `$fila` tiene que ser igual al de la query, por lo que en este caso tendría que ser `echo $fila['nombre']` @jofret

Comment: Hola que tal disculpa ayer no escribí el código bien , creo que fue por la hora, ahora estoy tratando de implementar el codigo de esta forma pero sigo sin conseguir el resultado, esperare tus comentarios. Saludos y gracias de antemano<blink>
       $peticion="SELECT imgen FROM ".$_GET["de"];
     $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$peticion);
     while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
      $elemento=$_GET["clav"];
      //echo $elemento."<br>";
      if($fila == $elemento) {
        continue;
      }
     echo $fila["imgen"]."<br>";
     } 
    </blink>

Comment: No funciona así? @jofret

Comment: hola si mira te escribí el código tal como lo estoy tratando de usar para evitar errores de escritura pero me devuelve toda la lista, no quita el elemento que llega $_Get["clav"]

Comment: Ya he visto el error, prueba a ver si con el código de la respuesta(lo he modificado) te funciona(Adaptalo a tus nombres de variables y todo eso) @jofret

Comment: hola, infinitas gracias, me sirve.

Comment: Si te sirve la respuesta por favor márcala como valida para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema pueda ayudarlo @jofret

Comment: claro que si, me sirvio mucho. Mil gracias